# Declaring an auto lambda function inside a class

Tags: c++, class, lambda, stl

I'm trying to declare a lambda compare function inside a class as such:

```
class Solve {
private:
    int n, q, first[N+1], depth[N+1], seg[_log(N)+2][(N<<1)+1];
    vector <int> G[N+1], euler;

    auto cmp = [euler, depth] (const int &a, const int &b) -> bool {
        return depth[euler[a]] < depth[euler[b]];
    };
...
```

But getting the error: `error: non-static data member declared with placeholder 'auto'`

Declaring the function as static doesn't help: `error: capture of non-variable 'Solve::euler'` + a bunch of other errors.
Explicitly using std::function <> didn't solve it either.

The function is intended for use as in `min(a, b, cmp);`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that does not depend on compiler extensions so I copy/paste and compile with my SO (paranoid) settings?

Comment: Sure: https://pastebin.com/RxRiyy4d
If you're asking for the whole code, this is it, but a lot of it is most probably useless: https://pastebin.com/CV1RJPLi
My compiler options are -Wall -O2 -std=c++11. Other than that, no changes have been made.

Thank you!

Comment: I think to use auto with functions you need to compile with c++14.

Comment: You cannot put a temporary function object in a class definition. That's contradicting the sense of lambda's. You may use a generator method instead, which returns a lambda.

Comment: It's just a member function. Why do you need to declare a member function this way? And you're capturing the members by value.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to *store* the lambda in your class. You can construct one when you need it.

I would create a method for that:

```
auto MakeComparator() const
{
    return [this](const int &a, const int &b) -> bool
    {
        return depth[euler[a]] < depth[euler[b]];
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a lambda function in the class definition. Move it to the constructor (`auto` is determined on compile, it's not gonna work here):

```
class Solve {
    ...
    std::function<bool(int, int)> cmp;
public:
    Solve() :
        cmp{ [&euler = this->euler, &depth = this->depth] (const int& a, const int& b) -> bool {
            return depth[euler[a]] < depth[euler[b]];
        } } {}
};
```

Comment: Either use initialization list or default (in place) member initializer.